# Calling two async functions

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I'm new to async and await and I'm thinking about calling two Stripe APIs in an express api endpoint. Is that possible?

```js
server.post('/ephemeral_keys', async (req, res) => {
    let customerId = req.body["customerId"];

    //TODO IF customerId is null create new one 
    //It got stuck here.
    customerId = await stripe.customers.create({
        description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
    });

    let key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create({
        customer: customerId
    }, {
        apiVersion: api_version
    }, );
    res.json(key);
});
```

error :DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: What do you mean "it got stuck here"?  Do you have a `try/catch` around your `await` calls so you can capture, log and handle errors?

Comment: Thank you. I wrapped each await part with try/catch as you said and that was the one to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple `await` lines in sequence, and the processing will run sequentially after each response comes back.

Note in your example that when the customer is created, you'll need to pull off the `id`, instead of using the full customer object in the second request:

```
server.post('/ephemeral_keys',async (req,res)=>{
  let customerId = req.body["customerId"];
 
  if (!customerId) {
    const newCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
      description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
    });
    customerId = newCustomer.id; // make sure to only use the id from the object
  }
  

  let key = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    { customer: customerId },
    { apiVersion: api_version }, 
  );
  res.json(key);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It's simple than I thought.

Comment: There is no error handling here at all.  So, if either `await` fails, this request will just never send any response.  Not the way to write server code.

Comment: That's correct - there is currently no error handling. This is a happy path simplified example. In practice you'll want to add error handling appropriate for your business. Happily, `await`-based error handling is very nice, as it works more or the same as synchronous try/catch structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement here:

```
...
//TODO IF customerId is null create new one 
if(!customerId) {
  customerId = await stripe.customers.create({
    description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
  });
}
...
```